# PHP: Parse url from css property

Tags: php, php4

I have a string from css (background property):

```
$sStr = 'url(http://www.ser.com/styles/../img/big-logo.gif) 10px 0 no-repeat';
```

Now I need the url of the image file like this:

```
'http://www.server.de/styles/../media/visuals/big-logo.gif'
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done a couple different ways, but in my opinion the easiest is regex.

```
if (preg_match('/url\(([^)]+)\)/i', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

Comment: @Ilyssis $regs[1] is what you want in this version

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/\((.*)\)/",  $sStr,  $matches);
print_r($matches);
```